# Select query even and odd value count

Tags: c#, ado.net

These methods give result, only if both `Image_ID1` and `Image_ID2` are not `null`.
If one of them or both of them are null, then it shows error.
Besides it returns only even value counts, odd value counts are skipped.
Example, Column `Image_ID1=1,3,null` and `Image_ID2=2,4,6`.
It has to show `1,2,3,4,6` values but it shows `1,2,3,4` values cause of that `null` value.
How can I solve these issues?

```
private void BindGrid()
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM images where Image_ID in (" + String.Join(",", getImage_ID()) + ")", con);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        gvImages.DataSource = dt;
        gvImages.DataBind();
    }
    private List<int> getImage_ID()
    {
        List<int> i = new List<int>();
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        string query = "Select Image_ID1, Image_ID2 from register where students_ID='" + getStudents_ID() + "'AND Image_ID1 IS NOT NULL AND Image_ID2 IS NOT NULL"; 
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        foreach (DbDataRecord s in reader)
            {
                i.Add(s.GetInt32(0));
                i.Add(s.GetInt32(1));
            }
        return i;
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get and in which line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use a single query/method:

```
string sql = @"
    SELECT img.* FROM
    (
        SELECT i.* FROM Images i
        INNER JOIN  register r
          ON i.Image_ID = r.Image_ID1
        WHERE r.students_ID = @studentsID

        UNION ALL

        SELECT i.* FROM Images i
        INNER JOIN  register r
          ON i.Image_ID = r.Image_ID2
        WHERE r.students_ID = @studentsID
    ) img
";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql , con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@studentsID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = getStudents_ID();
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of foreachloop in getImage_ID() method try below mentioned code

```
while (reader.Read()) 
{
if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Image_ID1")))
 i.Add(reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Image_ID1")));

if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Image_ID2")))
 i.Add(reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Image_ID2")));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this condition in your SQL

```
"'AND Image_ID1 IS NOT NULL AND Image_ID2 IS NOT NULL"
```

it should be instead

```
"'AND (Image_ID1 IS NOT NULL OR Image_ID2 IS NOT NULL)"
```

Then the `foreach` body should be

```
if (!s.IsDBNull(0)) i.Add(s.GetInt32(0));
if (!s.IsDBNull(1)) i.Add(s.GetInt32(1));
```